# Check a radio button depending on a recordset value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp-classic

**Situation summary:**

There is an HTML page with a few inputs that are used to filter recordsets.
The table with the records is drawn by a classic asp page.
Each row has some values displayed in editable input elements, that the user can alter and submit.
Some of these values are always either 0 or 1, so what I am trying to do is to make the user's life a bit easier by showing this value using a radio button instead of a textbox.

So I would like the radio button

```
<td>
   <input type="text" id="hidden_isDeleted" value="<%=rs("isDeleted")%>">
   <input type="radio" class="form" name="isDeleted" id="isDeletedNo" value="0"> 
   <input type="radio" class="form" name="isDeleted" id="isDeletedYes" value="1"> 
</td>
```

to be checked according to the following recordset value

```
<%= rs("isDeleted") %>
```

**What I have tried so far:**
My first attempt was to write a jQuery script to do this job:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($(#hidden_isDeleted).val() == 0) { 
    $("#isDeletedNo").prop("checked", true)
    }
  else {
    $("#isDeletedYes").prop("checked", true)
  }    
});
```

My second thought was to leave jQuery out since I am still new to it and use a simple javascript function which would be called by an `<body onload="checkIfDeleted()">` event from the radio itself.

```
function checkIfDeleted() {
  if ($(#hidden_isDeleted).val() == 0) {
    document.getElementById("isDeletedNo").checked = true;
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("isDeletedYes").checked = true;
  }
}
```

Does the `<body onLoad="checkIfDeleted()">` execute too soon? Or at least before the recordset is retrieved?

The reason that I used the hidden field was to first retrieve the value and then give the opportunity to the user to pick the other radio and thus change the value upon submit. I now that there is probably a better way to do this, but this is what I came up with in the first place.

**What I ended up doing:**

```
<td>
      <input type="radio" class="form" name="isDeletedRadio" id="in_isDeleted" value="0" <% If rs("isDeleted") = CLng(0) Then response.write("checked") End If%> >Έγκυρη 
      <input type="radio" class="form" name="isDeletedRadio" id="in_isDeleted" value="1" <% If rs("isDeleted") = CLng(1) Then response.write("checked") End If%> >Άκυρη
    </td>
```

And when it time comes to write the changes back to the database, I retrieve the value of the selected radio using the name of the radio, just like that:
`$('input[name="isDeletedRadio"]:checked').val();`

It's a nice and simple approach even though I don't like that much the VBscript stub in the radio buttons, so if anyone has a better idea I'll keep an eye on this question.

Comment: What do you need the hidden field for? Why do you not output the `checked` attribute dynamically on the right radio button using your server-side code already?

Comment: I edited the my question, I hope it answers yours.

Comment: _“and then give the opportunity to the user to pick the other radio and thus change the value upon submit”_ - and why would that need a hidden field? Your radio buttons will send either 0 or 1, depending on what the user chooses (or your pre-selection), that does not need a hidden field.

Comment: Imaging having an editable text field. On page load the asp page will write on that text either 0 or 1. The user can alter that price, however if the user is not careful enough he might enter whatever on that field. I wrote a working function that checks the value of that field onKeyUp and give a warning if it's not 0 or 1. Finally, the user might do some edits and submit the form. If I didn't use the hidden field then the radio would look like this

Comment: `<input type="radio" class="form" name="isDeleted" id="in_isDeletedNo" value="<%= rs("isDeleted") %>">Valid <input type="radio" class="form" name="isDeleted" id="in_isDeletedYes" value="<%= rs("isDeleted") %>">NotValid ` 
In that case, how is the user going to submit a different value for that variable? That is why I came up with the radio button and the hidden value.

Comment: _“how is the user going to submit a different value for that variable?”_ - what different value, I thought you want the user to _only_ be able to either chose 0 or 1?

Comment: if you pass the value of the record in the value of the radio button by writing value="<%= rs("isDeleted") %> in both radio buttons and the user wants to alter from 0 to 1 or vice versa then how is he going to achieve this with a radio button?

Comment: Of course you do not set both radio buttons to the same value, d’oh ... you set one to 0, and one to 1, because those are the values you want the user to be able to chose from.

Comment: I know my friend, but I also want, one of the two radio buttons to be checked when the page is loaded. And be checked according to a specific value.

Comment: Yeah, so? That’s what the `checked` attribute is for - so you only have to dynamically output it on one of the buttons.

Comment: You can't do this `if (<%= rs("isDeleted") %> == 0) {} else {}` The comparison would return a type mismatch, that is why I tried to pass the variable to a hidden field and retrieve it by `$(#hidden_isDeleted).val()`

Comment: Well then use the correct type to compare against?

Comment: I checked the type of the isDeleted as is returned by the query and it turns out that it's a vbLong (Long integer). Well, I'm quite new in Javascript but I don't think that I should convert anything before this comparison right?

Comment: Can’t you simple convert the 0 you are comparing this to, into a long integer as well? There should be casting functions or operators available for sth. like that.

Comment: Well it worked like a charm, thank you for the productive discussion/debugging !!! i ended up doing this:
`<input type="radio" class="form" name="isDeletedRadio" id="in_isDeleted" value="0" <% If rs("isDeleted") = CLng(0) Then response.write("checked") End If%> >Έγκυρη 
      <input type="radio" class="form" name="isDeletedRadio" id="in_isDeleted" value="1" <% If rs("isDeleted") = CLng(1) Then response.write("checked") End If%> >Άκυρη`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the  execute too soon? Or at least before the recordset is retrieved?

no, the function will fire after the page finishes loading. The recordset itself is populated BEFORE the page even starts to render. Remember, server side code ALWAYS executes before the page is loaded and rendered.

As for answering your question, and as others have pointed out, you don't need to include a hidden variable or any kind of javascript to run on page load, you can actually just embed the logic right in the html element, like so:

```
<td>
   <input type="radio" class="form" name="isDeleted" id="isDeletedNo" value="0" <% if rs("isDeleted") = false then %> checked="checked" %> > 
   <input type="radio" class="form" name="isDeleted" id="isDeletedYes" value="1" <% if rs("isDeleted") = true then %> checked="checked" %>> 
</td>
```

this assumes your isDeleted field in your database is of boolean or bit type. If it's a number or string, you would do something like:

```
<td>
   <input type="radio" class="form" name="isDeleted" id="isDeletedNo" value="0" <% if CStr( "" & rs("isDeleted") ) = "0" then %> checked="checked" %> > 
   <input type="radio" class="form" name="isDeleted" id="isDeletedYes" value="1" <% if CStr( "" & rs("isDeleted") ) = "1" then %> checked="checked" %>> 
</td>
```

I convert it to a string here in case the field contains no data, that way you won't get an error trying to compare a value to a null or blank error.

now, when you post, you'll be sending over the value from the radio button like you would any other form element:

```
dim isDeleted : isDeleted = Request.Form("isDeleted")
```

the value should return a 1 or zero, depending on what was selected.

Comment: That is exactly what i just did. Check the last of the comments to my question. The approach is very similar so I guess I have to accept your answer!